# Change access type to SNMP MIB object to read-write

Tags: linux, microcontroller, snmp, firmware, mib

Is it possible to change access type to specific SNMP MIB object from `read-only` (default)  to `read-write`? By modifying firmware.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is only feasible for objects in your enterprise private MIB documents. You cannot change objects that are in the standard MIB documents (those IETF ones for instance).

Second, how do you plan to modify firmware? If you do have the source code of the SNMP agent, you can make changes (according to that agent's specification) so as to change the access type of objects. As the details vary on agent framework, it is not possible to provide any further guidance here.

Comment: not clear, why do you mean there is no way to change access type to read-write by changing that in code?